# returning variables F#(canopy) easiest way

Tags: f#, web-testing, canopy-web-testing

```
 member x.Logovani(window : string) =
            let weburl = ref ""   
            let actwindow = ref ""     

            "Login" &&& fun _ ->
                browser.SwitchTo().Window(window) |> ignore
                weburl := currentUrl()
                actwindow := browser.CurrentWindowHandle
                return {|weburl,actwindow|}
 end
```

Hello my question is how to pass `weburl` and `actwindow`easiest way, because the way of my `return` is not working. I want to call function `Logovani` pass to that function var `window` and then recieved `weburl` and `actwindow`

Comment: I really doubt that `return` is correct here - the normal method would just be `weburl,actwindo` on its own as the last line.  But the answer would depend in what `&&&` does in canopy

Comment: Standard test definition with a name , but if you change it on `&&&&` its showing you your test in slow/debug mode  `"go somewhere, do some stuff, assert" &&& fun _ ->`

Comment: i have found the solution but need to post it out of comments. The point is that `member x.Logovani(window : string) : string ref =` by that first part i define what that function has to expect and the second part /new is what its returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally i fixed it like this

```
 member x.Logovani(window : string) : string ref =
            let weburl = ref ""   
                browser.SwitchTo().Window(window) |> ignore
                weburl := currentUrl()
            weburl
 end
```